# Get HTML source code from CefSharp web browser without Async

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a lot of trouble with cefSharp and the ChromiumWebBrowser. My company got a special software with special controls. The problem is, I need to get the whole HTML Code of a Webpage and can't use any kind of async method.

I searched and searched and wasn't able to find any source snippet which was able to help me.

Even here on Stack Overflow are a lot of snippets which may work in a Standaloneapplication but they won't work in our software.

Comment: Hi Feyre, still not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi SanM2009;

I need the whole webpage html for a customer. And with our tools it's absolutly impossible to get it with mainfram.GetSourceAsync()

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_GetSource.htm

Comment: If you cannot use async programming then CefSharp probably isn't a suitable fit for your application.

Comment: damn it... still thank you guys